# How Canvas relates to View's children

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

When I have a custom Android View (e.g. it extends FrameLayout) and I can draw on Canvas and I can add views with [addView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View)). How one relates to the other, e.g. when I draw sth on Canvas and I add some children which is at the top and which is at the bottom?

Comment: It depends on exactly where you're drawing in your custom `ViewGroup`. There are multiple methods which you can override to get access to a `Canvas`.

Comment: my particular custom view draws in onDraw()

Comment: You will have to call `setWillNotDraw(false)` for a `ViewGroup`'s `onDraw()` to be called. If you do that, anything drawn in `ViewGroup`'s `onDraw()` will be behind the child `View`s.